# Websocket @OnMessage is never firing for binary messages only text

Tags: java, tomcat, websocket, tomcat7, bytebuffer

I am writing a websocket communication with the `client` and `server` endpoints both in java code (using tomcat 7.0.53 as the web server) When I send a text message using the `session.getbasicremote.sendText(String)` method the `@Onmessage` function is fired and everything. However I want to send binary data between the websockets so thus have to use `session.getbasicremote.sendBinary(ByteBuffer)`. The code should then be read within the following method,

```
@OnMessage
public void recieved(ByteBuffer byteBuffer)
{
    System.out.println(byteBuffer);
}
```

However the method is never fired when the message is sent (I debugged through both remote debugging and print statements to verify that the binary data is being sent also yes regular text does get sent through this method when `binary` is switched to `text`). Does anyone have a clue why this method is never being called when the data is sent from the other end of the websocket? Here is also the code for the part where the binary data is sent over the websocket. Also the `@onError` methods are in the classes and never called either.

```
public void SendMessage() throws IOException
{
    for(int i = 0;i<MESSAGE_SIZE;i++)
        message+='\0';
    for(int i = 0;i<ID_SIZE;i++)
        id+='\0';
    ByteBuffer bbuf = ByteBuffer.allocate(1000);
    bbuf.put(id.getBytes());
    bbuf.position(33);
    bbuf.putInt(33,length);
    bbuf.position(37);
    bbuf.put(message.getBytes());
    for(Session session : sessionList)
        session.getAsyncRemote().sendBinary(bbuf);
    System.out.println("sent");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding the `ByteBuffer` flip method will do the trick the code will now look like as follows,

```
public void SendMessage() throws IOException
{
    for(int i = 0;i<MESSAGE_SIZE;i++)
        message+='\0';
    for(int i = 0;i<ID_SIZE;i++)
        id+='\0';
    ByteBuffer bbuf = ByteBuffer.allocate(1000);
    bbuf.put(id.getBytes());
    bbuf.position(33);
    bbuf.putInt(33,length);
    bbuf.position(37);
    bbuf.put(message.getBytes());
    bbuf.flip();
    for(Session session : sessionList)
        session.getAsyncRemote().sendBinary(bbuf);
    System.out.println("sent");
}
```

The flip method is the following according to the API documentation, `"the limit is set to the current position and then the position is set to zero. If the mark is defined then it is discarded.
After a sequence of channel-read or put operations, invoke this method to prepare for a sequence of channel-write or relative get operations"`.

Comment: i am sending arrayBuffer as  `var img = context.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    var binary = new Uint8Array(img.data.length);
    for (var i = 0; i < img.data.length; i++) {
        binary[i] = img.data[i];
    }
    sendBinary(binary.buffer);` i did't get your code working for me how to use it. help me out. onMessage is not calling. how can i send binary data